# Sorting a list by function leads to wrong result

Tags: python, sorting

When passing a list as an argument in function, why is the following list not changed?

```
def foo(*x):
    y=sorted(x)
    print(y)

a=[3,2,1]
```

The function is returning `[[3, 2, 1]]`, not `[[1,2,3]]`. Why is this happening? Is this something to do with call by value?

Comment: How are you calling the function exactly? Are you expecting `a` to change by simply calling `foo`? Furthermore, a question for you, what do you think the asterisk in your function definition means with respect to Python?

Comment: 1. That title is useless. 2. The formatting is broken, and the example makes no sense. 3. Because [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted), **as documented** returns a new list, it doesn't sort the old one (use [`list.sort`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort), which returns `None`, to sort in-place).

Comment: `def foo(*x):` what do you think the asterisk is doing in respect to `x`?

Comment: Your function is **not** returning `[[3, 2, 1]]`. It's _printing_ `[[3, 2, 1]]` and returning `None`. You're sorting a single element tuple, which happens to contain a 3 element list; that inner list is not affected.

Comment: What do you actually want `foo` to return? Do you want `[1, 2, 3]` or `[[1, 2, 3]]`?

Answer (score 1):

because the argument of your function is specified as *a, which is like saying your argument is a tuple of undefined dimension

when you try to sort a tuple with a nested list, the value will not change

infact as result you got a list of list (you got [[3, 2, 1]] not [3, 2, 1])

if you try this, it will work

```
def foo(*x): 
    y=sorted(x[0]) 
    print(y)
```

Comment: You could also note that `sorted()` returns a list regardless of what type of data structure is passed in.

Comment: Thank you . I understand now :)

Answer (score 1):

Why creating another function?
You can just do this

```
>>> a = [3,2,1]
>>> sorted(a)
[1, 2, 3]
```

However if you want to create another function. You have to call it.

```
def foo(x):
    y=sorted(x)
    return y
a = [3,2,1]
print(foo(a))
```

Comment: Thank you . I understand now :)

Answer (score 1):

As Blue Monday says, there's no need to create a new function for this, you should just call the `sorted` function. However, here are a couple of other ways to fix your code.

```
a = [3, 2, 1]

def foo1(*x):
    y = sorted(*x)
    print(x, y)
    return y

print(foo1(a))

def foo2(*x):
    y = sorted(x)
    print(x, y)
    return y

print(foo2(*a))
print(foo2(5, 4, 7, 6))
```

**output**

```
([3, 2, 1],) [1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
(3, 2, 1) [1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
(5, 4, 7, 6) [4, 5, 6, 7]
[4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Note that `foo2` expects us to pass in the items to sort as individual arguments. We can pass it a list (or tuple) by using the `*` "splat" operator in the function call. See [Unpacking Argument Lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists) in the official Python tutorial.