# When do I use **kwargs vs kwargs (*args vs args)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dereference, args, keyword-argument

I need to store both args & kwargs in a tuple for calling later, so in that case would the appropriate value in the tuple *args or args?  In other words, will this work:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self._buildCalls = [
        (self.__init__, args, kwargs)
    ]
    self._building = False

def __getattr__(self, attr):
    if self.building():
        if hasmethod(self, attr):
            return lambda *args, **kwargs: self.argSaver(attr, *args, **kwargs)
    else:
        return super().__getattr__(attr)

def argSaver(self, method, *args, **kwargs):
    self._buildCalls.append((method, args, kwargs))
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Did you try it - did it work?

Comment: You may find the examples in the answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40498298/4014959) helpful.

Comment: I’m not sure you actually understand what `*` and `**` are doing. But yes, you would have to store `args` and `kwargs` in the tuple; `*args` and `**kwargs` are not actual things you could store (but rather just the execution of another operator on `args` and `kwargs` respectively).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here's a sample function signature:

```
def foo(a, b, *args, **kwargs):
```

Here `*args` *represents* the arguments after `a` and `b` that aren't required, are passed like 'non-named' arguments (`foo(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)`) and the function gets them as a tuple called `args`: `args == (3, 4, 5)`.

`**kwargs` represents the arguments that aren't required, are passed by name (`foo(1, 2, foo=3, bar=4)`) and the function gets them as a dictionary called `kwargs`: `kwargs == {'foo': 3, 'bar': 4}`.

When you use the star notation outside function definition, it tries to extract data from a tuple or a dictionary, e.g. `*(1, 2, 3)` gives you three separate values that have been extracted from the tuple, `*{'foo': 5}` will extract all the keys of the dictionary, but `foo(**{'foo': 5, 'bar': 6})` will attempt to pass two arguments called `foo` and `bar` with values `5` and `6` respectively to the function `foo`.

Comment: Does anyone know why there is the following difference: `import csv`// `def convert(iter: str, **kwarg):` // `first_attempt_executes = csv.writer( open('file.txt','w'), **kwarg)` << Comple success!  //  `second_attempt_fails = csv.writer(csvfile= open('file.txt','w'), **kwarg)` << TypeError:  expected at least 1 argument, got 0